# Git does not ignore directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to figure out why `git` does not ignore a directory (virtual environment). Before adding and pushing files, I've created a `.gitignore` file which contains the line: `venv/`

Then I did:

```
git add .
git commit
git push -u origin --all
```

As you can see, it's there: [image]

Why is the directory not ignored, and how can I ignore it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139762/ignore-files-that-have-already-been-committed-to-a-git-repository

Comment: @Tacocat I did this and venv is still there. git rm -r --cached . ; git add . ; git commit -> nothing to commit, working directory clean

Answer (score 1):

Remove the folder from being tracked locally...

```
git rm -r --cached folderName
```

Comment: I did this and venv is still there. git rm -r --cached . ; git add . ; git commit -> nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Manually delete "venv" from github. Make some changes to your local repository and push to Github.  "Venv" should not reappear...

Comment: Also `git add .` will not ever delete files, only add changes... Try `git add --all` then commit and push. the `--all` option will stage deletions.